# How come $timeout updates the $rootScope variables from service to controller in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

I have following service :

```
App.service('DateTimeService',function($timeout,$rootScope)
{
    var rootThis = this;
    this.countUp = function() {
        DateTime1 = new Date();
        console.log(DateTime1);
        $timeout(rootThis.countUp, 5000);

        $rootScope.DateTime = DateTime1;
    }    
    $timeout(rootThis.countUp, 5000); 

})
```

This has been injected to the Controller :

```
var aController = function($scope, $rootScope, $location, $http,DateTimeService)
{

}
```

I have defined the following in angularJs view :

```
<span id="datetime">{{DateTime}}</span>
```

Now when I run this program, this DateTime automatically get updated into the view, As $rootScope.DateTime automatically got updated in the DateTimeService on recursive call.

How come ?, However I tried and search many ways so that dynamically updated value of some $rootScope variables in a service can be updated in AngularJs Scope and then view ? ( but I didn't find any?), now when I run the function inside the DateTime Service by calling this :  $timeout(rootThis.countUp, 5000); then it updates the value to the view ?

Answer (score 2):

`$timeout` actually calls `$scope.$apply()` when it finishes.
`$scope.$apply()` triggers a digest cycle,
since your `DateTime` is a `$rootScope` variable, it will get updated in the view in the digest cycle.

Comment: Wow ! I am beginner in angularJs, and good to know this concept. So do you think this could be one of the appropriate way to update $rootScope variables from service to controller and then on view.